# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, websphere

I have this error when I deploy my application in websphere portal

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/My_dataBase'
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils
```

So can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

The errors is self-explanatory - you are missing MySQL JDBC Connector JAR in classpath (MySQL JDBC connector can be downloaded from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

If you are using WebSphere portal, I guess you are using JDBC connections from JNDI. Then you should define MySQL JDBC provider with path pointing to MySQL JDBC driver JAR.

First copy MySQL JDBC Connector JAR on a machine where WAS is installed (e.g. /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar).

[image: Adding MySQL JDBC Provider]

Implementation class name is com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource

[image: Set path to MySQL JAR]

Then you define JDBC DataSource for that JDBC Provider and that's

If you are not using JDBC provided by WebSphere and use Spring to provide you with database connection, you should bundle MySQL JDBC Connector JAR with your WAR (e.g. by copying it into WEB-INF/lib or wherever your WAR lib directory is).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to package the MySQL jdbc driver jar with your code for deployment, or to create a shared library with that driver jar path included. You would then need to create a classloader on the application server in order to load the shared library upon startup.